# Wicket Jsp and web.xml

Tags: java, jsp, wicket, web.xml

I have a wicket project, but I have to include a jsp page, how can I do that? is it possible?

I added this to my web.xml with my jsp under WEB-INF

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cnsbWeb</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/consoleCnsb.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cnsbWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/consoleCnsb</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was the solution :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cnsbWeb</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/WEB-INF/consoleCnsb.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cnsbWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/consoleCnsb.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```